# Getting backend model in system.xml from config path in Magento 2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to get backend model class name from system.xml
Right now i am using this code.

magento/app/code/Company/Sso/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <section id="admin">
        <group id="sso_saml" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" >
            <label>Single Sign on(SAML)</label>
            <field id="is_enabled" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="0" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Is Enabled SAML</label>
                <comment>Enable Single Sign On</comment>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

Magento Code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$structure = $objectManager->create('Magento\Config\Model\Config\StructureFactory');
$field = $objectManager->create('Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure')->getElementByConfigPath('admin/sso_saml/is_enabled');
print json_encode($field->getData());
```

Output:

```
{"id":"is_enabled","path":"admin/sso_saml","_elementType":"field"}
```

But i need source_model, can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to get the value selected from `admin/sso_saml/is_enabled` ?

Comment: No. I need source_model or backend_model. In this case i want souce_model value "Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be in the adminhtml area in order to load the rest of the data:
e.g

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
$field = $objectManager->create('Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure')->getElementByConfigPath('customer/create_account/auto_group_assign');
echo $field->getData()['source_model'];
```

```
> Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno
```

You could potentially use `\Magento\Framework\App\State::emulateAreaCode` to fetch the data from within a non-admin context if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your solution worked.. i had to use emulate though

Answer (score 0):

Here is full solution after implementing Matt's solution.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$appState = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$field = $appState->emulateAreaCode('adminhtml', function($path){
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $appState = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $appState->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    $field = $objectManager->create('Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure')
        ->getElementByConfigPath($path->getPath());
    return $field;
}, [$path]);

$value = $path->getData()['backend_model'];
```